# Mapa da Google deu erro!

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Ola,

Estou a tentar adicionar um mapa no meu site usando a chave API mas aparece assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segui o tutorial a risca para não me enganar mas aparece como erro na minha pagina... alguem me consegue ajudar?

**Codigo:**

```css
#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
        <script>
                var map;
                function initMap() {
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: 38.736946, lng: -9.142685},
                    zoom: 9,
                  });
                }
              </script>
              <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA44NxTW1Z1B5uPHTnEaVj6eJK_2LJwWc4&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: Aqui está falando que sua chave foi deletada pelo google: `Google Maps JavaScript API error: DeletedApiProjectMapError
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#deleted-api-project-map-error`. Tem que fazer outra.

Comment: @AugustoVasques continua sem funcionar e ja mudei o meu api!

Comment: Por favor, não descaracterize a pergunta original de forma a invalidar as respostas existentes; você fez uma pergunta, ela foi respondida. Se ainda existem outros questionamentos, estes deverão ser feitos em novas perguntas, mas sempre respeitando os preceitos da comunidade definidos no guia de [How to Ask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) e na [help center](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve acessar https://console.developers.google.com e, depois de criar sua API KEY, vá até "Google Maps JavaScript API" e apenas HABILITAR (por padrão, DISABLE)

Comment: Isso funcionou inicialmente mas apareceu outro erro vou editar a pergunta.

Comment: @DavidMv Por favor, não descaracterize a pergunta original de forma a invalidar as respostas existentes; você fez uma pergunta, ela foi respondida. Se ainda existem outros questionamentos, estes deverão ser feitos em novas perguntas, mas sempre respeitando os preceitos da comunidade definidos no guia de [ask] e na [help].